# How to match generic string = generic string

Tags: regex, grep, string-parsing

Let's say I have this file:

```
AND 1=1
AND fejo = fejo
AND 4=5
AND 423=523
```

I want to match the lines which what is at the left of the `=` is the same as what there is at the right of the `=` symbol, so, it has to match the following lines:

```
AND 1=1
AND fejo = fejo
```

Comment: are you on Linux system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another pretty simple solution without having to make a huge mess:

`AND (\w+)\s*=\s*\1`

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -E '^AND\s+([^=\s]*)\s*=\s*\1\b'
```

works fine with your input.

#### The regex

```
^               # begin of line (preg tries to match the regex against each line)
AND             # match literal 'AND'
\s+             # match one or more whitespace characters
(               # beginning of a group
    [           # beginning of a character class that...
        ^       #    ... match any character that is not listed here:
        =       #    literal '='
        \s      #    whitespace
    ]           # end of the character class...
                # ... that matches one character that is not '=' or whitespace
    *           # zero or more occurrences of the previous expression (the class)
)               # end of the capturing group
\s*             # match zero or more spaces... 
=               # the '=' character
\s*             # ... around the equal sign
\1              # match the text captured by the first (and only) group above
\b              # match a word boundary, to make sure \1 is not just a prefix of a longer word
```

The `regex` above matches only the lines that start with uppercase `AND`. If you need to also match the lines that start with `and` (lowercase) or other uppercase/lowercase combination of these characters you can replace `AND` in the `regex` with `[aA][nN][dD]`.

Adding `-i` to the `grep` command line makes it ignore case both in the `regex` and in the input. The `regex` will match `and 1 = 1` but also `and fejo = FEJO` and this is probably not what you need.

Comment: Maybe add a `$` anchor at the end to make sure the thing to the right isn't a prefix match (a longer string which starts with the match).

Comment: `\s` isn't portable; maybe use POSIX `[[:space:]]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'split($0,a," *= *") && a[1]==($1 " " a[2])' file
AND 1=1
AND fejo = fejo
```

`split` splits record on `=` to `AND 1` and `1`, adds `$1` ie `AND` in the front of the `a[2]` ie `1` and compares. It fails if there are more than on space after `$1`. To avoid that, this seems to work also:

```
$ awk 'split($0,a,"( *= *| *)") && a[2]==a[3]' file
AND 1=1
AND fejo = fejo
```

Downside is that the compared elements can't have space in them. This one cleans the first word and its surrounding space off,  `śplit`s at `=` (surrounding space included) and compares the halfs.

```
$ awk ' {
    r=$0                     # working copy of record
    sub(/^ *[^ ]* */,"",r)   # remove AND
    n=split(r,a," *= *")     # split at = 
    if((n>1)&&a[1]==a[n])    # if r was really split in half and halfs match
        print
}' file
AND 1=1
AND fejo = fejo
```